# Eclipse android device window chooser is truncated

Tags: android, eclipse-mars

I recently installed the latest java released version of eclipse(mars). In my android application when i try to run the application and go to device window chooser it appears truncated.

[image]

Is this a bug? It also does not have the icon to make it full screen. If its  not a bug how can i correct the window to show default size